# fuchsia: Failed downloading prebuilt Jiri binary

Tags: fuchsia

I tried to get source code of fuchsia following the instructions.
https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/docs/+/master/development/source_code/README.md

```
zelongg@zelongg-ThinkPad-T430:/media/user/DATA/zelongg$ curl -s "https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/scripts/+/master/bootstrap?format=TEXT" | base64 --decode | bash
Cannot find prebuilt Jiri binary.
```

Could anyone share how to fix it?

I have no glue here.

Or anyone ever successfully downloaded the fuchsia source code?
Here is the verbose

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file of  the url ,then decode it  ,and add set -x to the bash file. Then run to check what is happing when have this error